# Django Admin: Order by value on related Foreign Key

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm trying to sort a Django Admin list page by a specific value in the objects' related foreign key set.

Specifically, in the below code, I want the ContentAdmin view to show a list of all content objects sorted by the "Twitter Score" (The Score object with name "Twitter").

In the django app I have the following models:

```
class Content(models.Model):
    body = models.CharField(max_length=564)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64) 

class Score(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    score = models.IntegerField()
    content = models.ForeignKey('Content')
```

And in the admin.py I have the following:

```
class ContentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'show_twitter_score',)

    def show_twitter_score(self, obj):
        twitter_score = obj.score_set.get(name='Twitter')
        return 'Twitter: ' + str(twitter_score.score)
```

GOAL: The admin panel for ContentAdmin displays the content objects ordered by "Twitter" scores

Thanks everyone!

Comment: By admin panel you mean `admin.py`? Do you have a `admin.site.register(Content, ContentAdmin)`?

Comment: My code doesn't do the ordering, it only displays the scores

Comment: Yep, by admin panel, I meant admin.py. Just fixed that

Also, I have all of the models registered correctly.

Comment: well it sounds bad but, did you try to click on the column header to do the sorting ?

Comment: @TommasoBarbugli, I wish it was me being that dumb! Unfortunately, clicking a column header doesn't work for columns defined as functions

Comment: @djs22 mea culpa I was not paying enough attention at your code :)

Comment: Posted my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10253503/309616. I'll mark it as correct once I'm allowed to do that!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved this by extending the `get_queryset` method of the `ContentAdmin` class. After that, it was just a matter of getting the right ORM query

```
def get_queryset(self, request):
    qs = super(ContentAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
    return qs.filter(score__name='Twitter').order_by('-score__score')
```

For Django 1.5 and earlier, the method was `queryset`.

```
def queryset(self, request):
    qs = super(ContentAdmin, self).queryset(request)
    return qs.filter(score__name='Twitter').order_by('-score__score')
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can try this from [ModelAdmin.list_display](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display) in Django's documentation:

> Usually, elements of `list_display` that aren't actual database fields can't be used in sorting (because Django does all the sorting at the database level).
>
> However, if an element of `list_display` represents a certain database field, you can indicate this fact by setting the `admin_order_field` attribute of the item.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> class Person(models.Model):
>     first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
>     color_code = models.CharField(max_length=6)
>
>     def colored_first_name(self):
>         return '<span style="color: #%s;">%s</span>' % (self.color_code, self.first_name)
>     colored_first_name.allow_tags = True
>     colored_first_name.admin_order_field = 'first_name'
>
> class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
>     list_display = ('first_name', 'colored_first_name')
> ```
>
> The above will tell Django to order by the first_name field when trying to sort by colored_first_name in the admin.

You can try this workaround in your code for the sorting.

Comment: Thanks Cesar, but I don't think this will work for me. Using list_display I have no way of specifying which of the multiple scores in the content_obj.score_set I want to order by.

Also, can I clarify my question for you? I want to make sure its understandable by everyone

Comment: Sure, just re-edit your post and change what you need. Sorry, maybe I misunderstood the whole thing, wouldn't be my first time :(

Comment: Made a small edit at the bottom for GOAL, but unfortunately I'm not how how else to word the question. Thanks for trying though Cesar!

Answer (score -3):

Since django admin uses the db to sort you cant sort on the function you are showing in the list.

What you can do is to add the column you want to show to the queryset that django admin is using to list your models, this way you can have sorting.

To add the column you need you have to use the queryset extra method.

This should do the trick :)

```
Content.objects.all().extra(select={'twitter_score': 'SELECT score from content_score WHERE content_score.id = content_content.id'})
```

BONUS ROUND:

Content.objects.all().extra(select={'twitter_score': 'SELECT 'Twitter score:' || score from content_score WHERE content_score.id = content_content.id'})

Comment: It's definitely possible to do this within the realms of the ORM. I found a solution for this that I'll be posting shortly, I'll comment here when I have :)

Comment: Actually, it'll be a while until I answer, I'm not allowed to for another 8 hours!

Comment: @djs22 i'm curious to see this one :)